# Space elevator idea

Tags: space-elevator, space-tether

Just wondering if it would be possible to make a space tether/elevator out of looped rubber bands like that of a loom bands like the common loom band?

Each time a new band is added for length, the weight of the band would be spread evenly over the bands already on the chain, the added weight would get smaller each time to the point of not being consequential?

I’m assuming there is an equation to say why this wouldn’t work?

Can someone set me straight on this?

Thanks

Comment: A rubber band would not survive exposition to space vacuum and very intensive solar radiation with a lot of UV very long. Besides that a material with much more strength per weight is needed. Even the best materials available today would not be useful for that task.

Comment: Previously: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/210801/could-one-extra-straw-literally-break-a-camels-back

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, it doesn't work.

What you are proposing is fundamentally the same as a chain.
The main issue is that gravity will apply to every single link.

While the mass of the links is equally distributed on the chain (ie each links have roughly the same weight), each link will need to carry the weight of each link below it (or your chain would just fall on the ground).

It's **exactly** the same a having a long tether.